# How to predict the dealer whether pick up the goods next month?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, regression, predictive-modeling

Here, I want to predict dealers(about 600) whether pick up the goods(about 30) next month. As you see, there are about 18,000 possibilities and it's difficult to predict.

By the way, now I have nearly three years'data(2017,2018 and 2019), and now I just use the common object in the last several months as the prediction.

For example, if dealer `A` purchases the goods `item 1` in September, October and November, then I predict he will purchases `item 1` in December. However, this is not exactly accurate, and the `precision` is about `0.6` while the `recall` is about `0.3`.

So any other way to predict it?

Comment: What algorithm are you currently using to predict that? If you are using regression, how are you performing it?

Comment: Now I don't use any algorithm, just use some rules to get prediction.

Comment: My suggestion would be to look into logistic regression. It seems quite appropriate for your task.

Answer (score 1):

**Sure.**

Question you should answer is it [multiclass or mutlilabel](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html).

In any case I would really advise you to take a look at this list of similiar [problems/competitions](https://ndres.me/kaggle-past-solutions/). Since your question is open-ended I could write 10 pages of approaches. Yours best bet is to invest some time, find similiar problem and look what other people did and dig it up.

Comment: Thanks, actually I think my problem is more difficult, because it's similar to time series prediction, and there are not many samples (only three years' data).